# Extracting payload from raw hex

Tags: perl, awk, grep, wireshark, cut

I'm currently trying to extract the raw payload from an ICMP packet.

I've managed to trim it down to the format I like (without the first 5 characters on each line and without the ....... stuff).

Original format:

```
0000  ca fe 00 00 ba be de ad 00 00 be ef 08 00 45 00   ..............E.
0010  00 4c 00 01 00 00 40 01 9b 48 c0 a8 01 c8 b9 f5   .L....@..H......
0020  63 02 08 00 10 b4 00 00 00 00 50 4b 03 04 14 00   c.........PK....
0030  09 00 08 00 92 ac 88 51 e2 f5 38 a1 6d 70 03 00   .......Q..8.mp..
0040  94 72 03 00 08 00 1c 00 66 6c 61 67 2e 6a 70 67   .r......thing.jpg
0050  55 54 09 00 03 d3 e3 cf 5f e7                     UT......_.
```

Scripts:

`awk '{x="";x=substr($0,5,50);gsub(/ +/,"",x);print x}' nontrimmed.txt > raw.txt`

`tr -d "\n" < raw,txt > newraw.txt`

Result:

```
cafe0000babedead0000beef08004500004c0001000040019b48c0a801c8b9f56302080010b400000000504b030414000900080092ac8851e2f538a16d7003009472030008001c00666c61672e6a70675554090003d3e3cf5fe7cafe0000babedead0000beef08004500004c0001000040019b48c0a801c8b9f5630208005b5000000000e3cf5f75780b000104e803000004e80300003bc....ect
```

However, I'd like to get a specific number of bytes every x characters - i.e this:

ca fe 00 00 ba be de ad 00 00 be ef 08 00 45 00
00 4c 00 01 00 00 40 01 9b 48 c0 a8 01 c8 b9 f5
63 02 08 00 10 b4 00 00 00 00 **50 4b 03 04 14 00

09 00 08 00 92 ac 88 51 e2 f5 38 a1 6d 70 03 00

94 72 03 00 08 00 1c 00 66 6c 61 67 2e 6a 70 67

55 54 09 00 03 d3 e3 cf 5f e7**

Would become this:

```
504b030414000900080092ac8851e2f538a16d7003009472030008001c00666c61672e6a70675554090003d3e3cf5fe7
```

Instead of this:

```
cafe0000babedead0000beef08004500004c0001000040019b48c0a801c8b9f56302080010b400000000504b030414000900080092ac8851e2f538a16d7003009472030008001c00666c61672e6a70675554090003d3e3cf5fe7cafe0000babedead0000beef08004500004c0001000040019b48c0a801c8b9f5630208005b5000000000e3cf5f75780b000104e803000004e80300003bc....ect
```

But for multiple different ones of the same format:

```
0000  ca fe 00 00 ba be de ad 00 00 be ef 08 00 45 00   ..............E.
0010  00 4c 00 01 00 00 40 01 9b 48 c0 a8 01 c8 b9 f5   .L....@..H......
0020  63 02 08 00 10 b4 00 00 00 00 50 4b 03 04 14 00   c.........PK....
0030  09 00 08 00 92 ac 88 51 e2 f5 38 a1 6d 70 03 00   .......Q..8.mp..
0040  94 72 03 00 08 00 1c 00 66 6c 61 67 2e 6a 70 67   .r......flag.jpg
0050  55 54 09 00 03 d3 e3 cf 5f e7                     UT......_.

0000  ca fe 00 00 ba be de ad 00 00 be ef 08 00 45 00   ..............E.
0010  00 4c 00 01 00 00 40 01 9b 48 c0 a8 01 c8 b9 f5   .L....@..H......
0020  63 02 08 00 5b 50 00 00 00 00 e3 cf 5f 75 78 0b   c...[P......_ux.
0030  00 01 04 e8 03 00 00 04 e8 03 00 00 3b c1 7d b7   ............;.}.
0040  30 0b ce 53 1e 99 d2 3a 1b 83 4c 7c be cd ef fa   0..S...:..L|....
0050  54 86 4d 24 19 58 c5 a9 b1 4d                     T.M$.X...M

0000  ca fe 00 00 ba be de ad 00 00 be ef 08 00 45 00   ..............E.
0010  00 4c 00 01 00 00 40 01 9b 48 c0 a8 01 c8 b9 f5   .L....@..H......
0020  63 02 08 00 3e f4 00 00 00 00 dd 56 4c 00 11 bf   c...>......VL...
0030  42 22 2a 52 86 75 01 0a e2 90 90 f5 2b ec d0 67   B"*R.u......+..g
0040  74 5a 17 70 05 b6 27 35 21 cf 98 fb a2 5e 82 a8   tZ.p..'5!....^..
0050  56 f9 05 05 3d 3e 80 3f 68 23                     V...=>.?h#
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some explanation on the logic behind extracting 504? Is it the same location in the string each time?

Comment: Why not simply use `xxd -r` ?

Comment: Yes, same location each time (from characters 42 - 89) in each block

Comment: "But for multiple different ones of the same format:" - what?

Comment: The `tr` command you're running is outputting something that is not a text file per the POSIX standard btw (since it's removing ALL `\n`s but text files are required to contain at least one `\n` at the end) so YMMV with what any text processing tool you subsequently run on that does with it. You should make it `{ tr -d '\n' < raw.txt; printf '\n'; } > newraw.txt` so that `newraw.txt` is still a POSIX text file if you really want to use that approach (but there are better approaches and you don't need to do any of that for your specific problem).

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -v OFS= '{$1=$NF=""; x=x $0} END{print substr(x,85)}' file
504b030414000900080092ac8851e2f538a16d7003009472030008001c00666c61672e6a70675554090003d3e3cf5fe7
```

The above was run against your "Original format" input file:

```
$ cat file
0000  ca fe 00 00 ba be de ad 00 00 be ef 08 00 45 00   ..............E.
0010  00 4c 00 01 00 00 40 01 9b 48 c0 a8 01 c8 b9 f5   .L....@..H......
0020  63 02 08 00 10 b4 00 00 00 00 50 4b 03 04 14 00   c.........PK....
0030  09 00 08 00 92 ac 88 51 e2 f5 38 a1 6d 70 03 00   .......Q..8.mp..
0040  94 72 03 00 08 00 1c 00 66 6c 61 67 2e 6a 70 67   .r......thing.jpg
0050  55 54 09 00 03 d3 e3 cf 5f e7                     UT......_.
```

If your input file can contain multiple records then:

```
$ awk -v OFS= '{$1=$NF=""; $0=$0; x=x $0} !NF{print substr(x,85); x=""} END{print substr(x,85)}' file
504b030414000900080092ac8851e2f538a16d7003009472030008001c00666c61672e6a70675554090003d3e3cf5fe7
e3cf5f75780b000104e803000004e80300003bc17db7300bce531e99d23a1b834c7cbecdeffa54864d241958c5a9b14d
dd564c0011bf42222a528675010ae29090f52becd067745a177005b6273521cf98fba25e82a856f905053d3e803f6823
```

That second script was run against the block of 3 records under "But for multiple different ones of the same format:" at the end of your question but you didn't provide the expected output for it so idk if that's the expected output or not:

```
0000  ca fe 00 00 ba be de ad 00 00 be ef 08 00 45 00   ..............E.
0010  00 4c 00 01 00 00 40 01 9b 48 c0 a8 01 c8 b9 f5   .L....@..H......
0020  63 02 08 00 10 b4 00 00 00 00 50 4b 03 04 14 00   c.........PK....
0030  09 00 08 00 92 ac 88 51 e2 f5 38 a1 6d 70 03 00   .......Q..8.mp..
0040  94 72 03 00 08 00 1c 00 66 6c 61 67 2e 6a 70 67   .r......flag.jpg
0050  55 54 09 00 03 d3 e3 cf 5f e7                     UT......_.

0000  ca fe 00 00 ba be de ad 00 00 be ef 08 00 45 00   ..............E.
0010  00 4c 00 01 00 00 40 01 9b 48 c0 a8 01 c8 b9 f5   .L....@..H......
0020  63 02 08 00 5b 50 00 00 00 00 e3 cf 5f 75 78 0b   c...[P......_ux.
0030  00 01 04 e8 03 00 00 04 e8 03 00 00 3b c1 7d b7   ............;.}.
0040  30 0b ce 53 1e 99 d2 3a 1b 83 4c 7c be cd ef fa   0..S...:..L|....
0050  54 86 4d 24 19 58 c5 a9 b1 4d                     T.M$.X...M

0000  ca fe 00 00 ba be de ad 00 00 be ef 08 00 45 00   ..............E.
0010  00 4c 00 01 00 00 40 01 9b 48 c0 a8 01 c8 b9 f5   .L....@..H......
0020  63 02 08 00 3e f4 00 00 00 00 dd 56 4c 00 11 bf   c...>......VL...
0030  42 22 2a 52 86 75 01 0a e2 90 90 f5 2b ec d0 67   B"*R.u......+..g
0040  74 5a 17 70 05 b6 27 35 21 cf 98 fb a2 5e 82 a8   tZ.p..'5!....^..
0050  56 f9 05 05 3d 3e 80 3f 68 23                     V...=>.?h#
```